# Custom Task Sequence - script installer at start up

Tags: sccm

I have a Powershell script that is stored on the server. I then wrapped this script into a package in SCCM. I now have a custom task sequence and I was looking into variables such as SMSRebootMessage and SMSRebootTimeout but I couldn't get it to work. The machines that I'm targeting to test this are not part of any OS upgrade. They are on Windows 7. My goal is to:

1. Notify user there's an available software (via Software Center notification) | This usually shows up when deploying a TS to a collection so no assistance with this step.
2. The user's machine then reboots with no other actions.
3. After reboot the script/package run at Win PE or at startup.

Kindly show steps how I can perform this.
Thank you

Comment: This is what I have so far after many failed attempts:
Tasks in sequence:
1. SMSRebootMesage = Value true
2. Restart Computer = "the currently installed default OS"
2a. checked box for "Notify the user before restarting"
2b. Message display time-out 10 seconds
3. Run Powershell Script

Comment: Why does your script have to run at WinPE or StartUp? And why doesn't it matter whether is WinPE or full OS?

Comment: It is to delete the C:\$WINDOWS.~BT. I have remote sites that I need to have this script run on that environment. I've tried all that I can but some machines I cannot delete this folder because for some reason some anti-virus, network monitoring tools etc have .dll process running on that folder. These applications are not stopping the orginzation's Win 10 project. It just happens that some machines, we cannot delete the BT folder. My only option is what I asked for.

Comment: So you've already got a TS which boots into WinPE but then your script/package fails to run? Have you attempted to run your script manually during WinPE? Some cmdlets are not available during WinPE, only full OS. You might have to use wpeutil commands instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/wpeutil-command-line-options